# Subset in R does not seem to work : Value of rows with specific values to be subset

Tags: r

I have a dataset train dataset.

```
train$date<- ydm(train$date) #from format year-date-month
train$item<- as.factor(as.character(train$item))
train$store<- as.factor(as.character(train$store))
train$yearmonth <- format(as.Date(train$date), "%Y%m")
head(train)

date store item sales yearmonth
1 2013-01-01     1    1    13    201301
2 2013-01-02     1    1    11    201301
3 2013-01-03     1    2    14    201301
4 2013-01-04     1    1    13    201301
5 2013-01-05     1    1    10    201301
6 2013-01-06     1    2    12    201301
```

Now I simply wish to calculate the rows for which store id = 1, but I am not able to achieve that.

```
train_1 <- subset(train, train$store==1)
```

train_1 has the exact number of rows as train which should not have been the case.

Little bit about the structure after all the operations

```
sapply(train,class)
       date       store        item       sales 
     "Date"    "factor"    "factor"   "integer" 
  yearmonth 
"character"
```

Comment: Does R throw an error after `train_1 <- subset(train, train$store == 1)`? I am not sure i understand your data fully, but seems to me that `1` in the `subset` call is the factor level, in which case you should use `"1"` instead. If this does not solve the issue please provide a sample data set to reproduce the issue (you can use `dump("train", "")` for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that there are leading/lagging spaces and also it is a `factor` class.  So, an option is to either trim the spaces with `trimws`

```
train_1 <- subset(train, trimws(store) == 1)
```

Or convert to `character` and subset

```
train_1 <- subset(train, as.character(store) == '1')
```

Or use `grepl`

```
train_1 <- subset(train, grepl('1', store))
```

### Update

The subset removed 90% of the rows exactly from 913000 to 91300.  There was a confusion in the numbers.

---

Using the OP's dataset

```
train <- read.csv(file.choose())
str(train)
#'data.frame':  913000 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ date : Factor w/ 1826 levels "2013-01-01","2013-01-02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# $ store: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ item : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ sales: int  13 11 14 13 10 12 10 9 12 9 ...
train_y <- subset(train, store == 1)
dim(train_y)
#[1] 91300     4
unique(train_y$store)
#[1] 1
```

Comment: With trimws, I am still getting the same number of rows, when i double click train_1 , I get store =10,2 and 3 etc. values too...Second case, the number of rows reduced, however when i expand and see by double clicking on the variable, again there are rows with store =10,2,3,4,5 etc. Original dataframe has 90,000 rows

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor. can you check `levels(train$store)`

Comment: `levels(train$store)
 [1] "1"  "10" "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9" `

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor try `train_1 <- subset(train, as.character(store) == '1')`

Comment: Tried this, again the number of rows is 90,000 rows.

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor that is strange because `trimws` or `as.character` should have worked.  Do you NA elements

Comment: Try `train_1 <- subset(train, as.character(store)  %in%'1')`

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor try the above code with `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: This too does not work. I can mail you the dataset if you want.

Comment: sent. please check and if you can solve this, pls revert

Comment: sure, will check now

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor your initial dataset is `913000` rows. after subsetting it is `91300` one zero is removed